# Как заставить браузеры отображать background-image при печати?

Tags: html, css, pdf

Нужно было сделать темплэйт для конвертации в PDF, но была проблема в фоновой картинке, при отправке на печать она не отображалась.
Я попробовал исправить ситуацию с помощью свойств CSS

```
 -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
  color-adjust: exact !important;
```

но это не помогло.

Comment: Это так-то включается вручную пользователем в настройках печати. Фоновые картинки для того и фоновые, что их потеря не должна как-то негативно влиять на отображение главного содержимого страницы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант который я использовал для решения это **вместо background-image использовать обычный**   c помощью position: absolute повесил как фон, а блок с текстом через z-index и position : relative;